# Backup of whole harddrive during full operation with Acronis True Image Home 2010?

Tags: backup, acronis-trueimage

Currently, I'm creating a backup of one of my hard drives. It's my main hard drive, where the operating system is running. Because the backup is done during full operation **I'm asking if the backup really includes all files (registry, ...)**? For example, can I restore the backup on another hard drive and then run the operating system again without problems?

Normally I would say that you have to boot from a CD (without running OS) to make a backup.

I made a Google research but I didn't found my case so far.

Comment: If it is a disk image backup it will have everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a feature call [Volume Shadow Copy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee923636%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) that is designed to produce consistent backups from a running system. Doubtless Acronis makes use of this.